# What is the technical term for the set formed by the solution to Ax = b?

Tags: geometry

One linear equality constraint $w^Tx=b$ defines a hyper-plane. The intersection of several equality constraints $Ax=b$ defines a *THING*.

I am looking for the technical term. It isn't a linear subspace, since the origin may not be in the set.

Thanks!

Comment: It's an *affine subspace*.